# AppLaunchChecker, where is the data stored?

Tags: android, android-support-library

As [Android Support Library, revision 23.3.0 (April 2016)](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) google announced the new Api [AppLaunchChecker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/AppLaunchChecker.html).
I just wanted to know how and where does the system store the data. Does it store it as a shared preference, or does it store somewhere else ...

I already read the docs but I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation: [AppLaunchChecker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/AppLaunchChecker.html) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/AppLaunchChecker.html

> To help track how your app has been launched by the user in the past. This can be useful if you want to confirm that a user has launched your app through its front door activity from their launcher/home screen, rather than just if the app has been opened in the past in order to view a link, open a document or perform some other service for other apps on the device.

Thus, this new utility class is nothing more than the typical “workaround” based on **SharedPreferences** already used by many developers: when the launcher Activity is created, a boolean shared preference is set to true, then later in the **lifecycle** of the application, calling **hasStartedFromLauncher**, we simply get its value.

This utility class is only useful to know if the application has been launched from the home screen at least once in the past but not every time it’s launched: in fact, after the fist time, you will always get **true** from **hasStartedFromLauncher**.

To answer your question: The data is kept in **SharedPreferences**.

Comment: Thank you for answering but i need an answer which refer to a clear documentation which indicate it. My guess is the same as you, It store data in Shared preference bu t at least it should have been mentioned once somewhere !